# correct way to create a lowercase search string swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, string, search

I need string to use in the search function in my app. I don´t have much coding experience, but get by by googling a lot, tutorials, and some trial and error.

The below approach works, it creates just what I need, but I noticed it slows down compiling time substantially, so I assume that there is a better/smarter way to do this? I did not get much in a way of answers by googling on this one.

```
 let searchText: String? = ("\(self.noseTextView?.text)"
+"\(self.palateTextField?.text)"+"\(self.finishTextField?.text)"
+"\(self.overallTextField?.text)"+"\(self.otherTextField?.text)"
+"\(self.glassTextField?.text)"+"\(bottleName2)"
+"\(self.distilleryTextField?.text)").lowercased()
```

Anyone that can teach me a better way to achieve the same result?

Edit:

One answer adapted to my code, (or my interpretation of it from Özgür Ersil, below), that works.

```
//creates lowercase String for labels to save compiling time
func getText(textLabel: UILabel)->String{
    return textLabel.text!.lowercased()
}
    //creates lowercase String for TextFields to save compiling time
func getTextTF(ui: UITextField)->String{
    return ui.text!.lowercased()
}
    //creates lowercase String for TextViewsto save compiling time
func getTextTV(ui: UITextView)->String{
    return ui.text!.lowercased()
}

let searchText: String = self.getTextTV(ui: self.noseTextView) +
 self.getTextTF(ui: self.palateTextField) + self.getTextTF(ui: 
self.finishTextField) + 
self.getTextTF(ui: self.overallTextField) + self.getTextTF(ui: 
self.otherTextField) + 
self.getTextTF(ui: self.glassTextField) + self.getTextTF(ui: self.bottleName) +
 self.getTextTF(ui: self.distilleryTextField)
```

Comment: Try put all those string into array then use `.joined().lowercased()`, but for compiling time, are you sure this is the thing causing that?

Comment: i think lowercase will not take so much compile time , can u please tell how did u found compile time over this line of code

Comment: I've read some where that mostly dictionary with Any or multi level one can cause compile time, never heard of string

Comment: Hi, I have not tested it "formally", but a quick manual count, shows that if I uncomment this, the whole app compiles in 13 sec, but if this line is included it uses 50 seconds.

Comment: So I would do somthing like: var arrayOfStrings: [("\(self.noseTextView?.text)",
"\(self.palateTextField?.text)","\(self.finishTextField?.text)"
,"\(self.overallTextField?.text)","\(self.otherTextField?.text)"
,"\(self.glassTextField?.text)","\(bottleName2)". 
,"\(self.distilleryTextField?.text)")] then, searcText = arrayOfStrings.joined().lowercased()  ?

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to append optional strings into a single String

```
 func append(optionalStrings arrStrings : [String?],separator: String = " ") -> String {

        return arrStrings.flatMap{$0}.joined(separator: separator)
 }
```

This function takes an array of optional Strings as parameter

**flatMap** is a higher order function purpose of which here is to eliminate the nil value in arrayStrings(if exists) and provide us a array of non-Optional Strings which we can join with **joined(separator: String)** method.

You can use this as

```
 let arrOptionalStrings = [noseTextView?.text,
        palateTextField?.text,
        finishTextField?.text,
        overallTextField?.text,
        otherTextField?.text,
        glassTextField?.text,
        bottleName2,
        distilleryTextField?.text
    ]
let searchText: String? = append(optionalStrings: [str1,str2].map({ $0?.lowercased() }))
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the extensive reply. However I get, "map" produces `[T]` not the expected contextual result type "String?" as an error on: let searchText: String? = arrOptionalStrings.map{ $0.lowercased() }

Comment: Edited it. Missed a "?" after $0 in map as the array is of OptionalStrings we have to use optional Chaining